# Mathieu-like equation and its analysis

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I have an equation
$$
\tag 1 \frac{\partial^{2} y}{\partial t^{2}} - \frac{\partial^{2}y}{\partial z^{2}} + i\frac{\partial a(t)}{\partial t}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = 0
$$
Here 
$$
a = \frac{J_{\frac{1}{4}}(t^{2})}{\sqrt{t}} \approx -\frac{3}{4}\frac{cos\left(t^{2} - \frac{3\pi}{8}\right)}{t^{\frac{3}{2}}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} = a_{0}\frac{cos\left(t^{2} - \frac{3\pi}{8}\right)}{t^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$
For large values of time $t$ I may also simplify the derivative $\frac{\partial a}{\partial t} = a'$ to the form
$$
\tag 2 a{'} \approx - 2a_{0}\frac{sin\left(t^{2} - \frac{3\pi}{8}\right)}{\sqrt{t}}
$$
I need to analyze Eq. $(1)$ on instabilities. In Fourier space it reads
$$
y_{k}{''} + (k^{2} + Ak a{'})y_{k} = 0, \quad A = const, \quad y_{k} \equiv y(k, t)
$$
It is Mathieu-like equation: by using $(2)$ it takes the form
$$
\tag 3 y_{k}{''} + \left[k^{2} - \tilde{A}k \frac{sin\left( t^{2} - \frac{3 \pi}{8}\right)}{\sqrt{t}}\right]y_{k} = 0
$$ 
Or how to build approximate solution? Especially I look for exponentially growing solutions.

An edit. For large argument $t$ is is possible to transform $(3)$ to Mathieu-like equation with time-dependent parameters. Due to adiabaticity of these parameters it is possible to get exponent of the unstable solution and the bands of parameters which correspond to unstable solution.

Answer (score 1):

By $y_k$ do you mean $y(k,t)$? What you have is a PDE with only time derivatives, and so the general solution is given by 
$$y(k,t)=f_1(k)\cos(k^2+Aka')t+f_2(k)\sin(k^2+Aka')t,$$
for general functions $f_1,f_2$, which would be determined if you had an initial condition for $y$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$.

Comment: Even by taking into the account that $a{'}$ depends on $t$?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that